# The process has been signaled with signal "9"

Tags: php, symfony

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
The process has been signaled with signal "9".
```

Suddenly i've started to get this error message while dumping assets in symfony 2.5.0 I've never seen this error before. It randomly appears and stops dump process. I run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod` on virtual server.

Comment: This might actually be a ressources problem. You might want to check your server's virtual hardware.

Comment: @i.am.michiel ,  Thanks, virtual server just ran out of memory.