# Symfony Uncaught exception - 'The process has been signaled with signal "9"

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, twig

Im getting this error when trying to create a PDF document using Phantomjs and Symfony's Process and Reposonse files.

This is the error message i recieve

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The process has been signaled with signal "9".'

Here is my code below: Controller File

```
    namespace PhantomFox\Capture;

    use PhantomFox\Views\View;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    class Capture
    {   
        protected $view;
        protected $pdf;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->view = new View;
        }

        public function load($filename, array $data = [])
        {
            $view = $this->view->load($filename, $data);

            $this->pdf = $this->captureImage($view);
        }

        public function respond($filename)
        {
            $response = new Response(file_get_contents($this->pdf), 200, [
                'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            ]);

            unlink($this->pdf);

            $response->send();
        }

        protected function captureImage($view)
        {
            $path = $this->writeFile($view);

            $this->phantomProcess($path)->setTimeout(10)->mustRun();

            return $path;
        }
    protected function writeFile($view)
    {
        file_put_contents($path = 'app/tmp/storage/' . md5(uniqid()) . '.pdf' , $view);

        return $path;
    }

    public function phantomProcess($path)
    {
        return new Process('app/bin/phantomjs capture.js ' . $path);
    }

}
```

This is my view file:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->capture->load('index.html', [
            'order' => '123456',
            'name' => 'Wes Murray',
            'amount' => 100.00,
        ]);

        $this->capture->respond('index.pdf');

    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same exception when I tried to encode a 4k video into different resolutions using FFmpeg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this post [The process has been signaled with signal "9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848994/the-process-has-been-signaled-with-signal-9) this might be related to your host running out of memory.

i.am.michiel Mar 4 at 7:56

> This might actually be a ressources problem. You might want to check
>   your server's virtual hardware.

Dmitry Mar 4 at 11:56

> @i.am.michiel , Thanks, virtual server just ran out of memory.

Check if your server settings and hardware are suited for the kind of PDF operations you want to run.

Comment: Im not using a Virtual Server, im running the Apache Stack on Mac OSX, Hardware: Core i5 - 8GB Ram and 500GB HDD. i have adjusted the memory limit but no luck

Comment: I had similar issue, changed the amount of RAM assigned for my VM and it worked afterwards. This is a memory issue then. I increased from 2048 to 8192 MB

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur when you change your supervisord configuration.

When you change the configuration and run reread and update commands, the supervisord will send stopsignal to the child processes. If they are not finished within a time specified by stopwaitsecs config variable, they are killed with 9 signals.

In my case, I was using Laravel and I had to set the stopwaitsecs value to be larger then my longest running job ( as is actually mentioned in documentation )