# Laravel: Error in running the scheduled cron jobs

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, cron, laravel-vapor

I'm using Laravel 9 (deployed to AWS with Laravel Vapor) for a project and also have some jobs scheduled to run on `App\Console\Kernel.php`.

Here's my `Kernel.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Notifications\FirstMonthRecognitionNotification;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('tenants:run job:dispatch --argument=job=UpdateTenantCacheJob');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, I'm using multi-tenancy.

However, recently, I've been getting this error occasionally in my app's error logs:

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException/var/task/artisan schedule:run --no-interaction
> The process has been signaled with signal "9".

Does anybody have any similar experience? How can this be solved/avoided?

Comment: host run out of memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146878/symfony-uncaught-exception-the-process-has-been-signaled-with-signal-9/33147159#33147159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. I needed to increase the queue worker's memory by setting the `queue-memory` variable on my `vapor.yml` file. Hope this helps anyone having a similar issue.

Comment: The default value is 512 (MB), so you need to set a value greater than that. I went for 2048 MB.